# syntax error Bash command bc

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, bc

I am having a problem with the bc command. The output generated is:

```
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
```

Here I post my code, any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
value="100%"          # the threshold to cause a break out
kb="kB/s"
mb="MB/s"             # strings to mask out
conversor=1024        # kb->mb conversion
contador=0            # initalize our total in megabytes
for ((x=3; x<=${#array[@]}; x+=5)); do
    paraula=${array[$x]};

    if [[ $paraula =~ .*kB.* ]]; then
        paraula=${paraula%$kb}
        paraula=$(echo "scale=4; $paraula/$conversor" | bc) # convert to $mb
        contador=$(echo "scale=4; $contador+$paraula" | bc)
        echo "Counting: "$contador
    else
        paraula=${paraula%$mb}
        contador=$(echo "scale=4; $contador+$paraula" | bc)
        echo "Counting: "$contador
    fi

    if [[ " ${array[$x]} " =~ " $value " ]]; then
        break;
    fi
    echo "Value : ${array[$x]} ";

done 

echo "final value: $contador"
```

then, the error on the terminal after execute the script is

[image: error]

Comment: Can you simplify this to a [mcve]? You can probably get the same error from a single line of code that does nothing but invoke `bc`.

Comment: Consider using `bash -x yourscript` to log everything the script does, to find the place where it first goes wrong. If you want the tracking to be a bit easier, you can assign a value to `PS4` that includes line number; for example, all on one line you could run: `PS4=':${LINENO}+' bash -x yourscript`. (Note that for security reasons, `PS4` has to be set inside your script itself in very new versions of bash if that script is running as root).

Comment: BTW, please add the above-requested logs as text to the question, not screenshots. See the accepted answer to [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: Can you `echo` the values of `paraula` and `contador` before you feed it to `bc`?

Comment: Jesuuuuuuus, that was the problem. On my last row, I added to the counting a %. Thank you so much!

Comment: I had to edit some indents (and comments) in there.  Your code needs to be readable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your last line doesn't have a newline in it, when piped to bc.

This works fine.

```
$ echo "scale=4; 2046/1024" | bc
1.9980
$ echo -e "scale=4; 2046/1024\n" | bc
1.9980
```

This is broke

```
$ echo -n "scale=4; 2046/1024" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I think you can change to

```
contador=$(echo -e "scale=4; $contador+$paraulao\n" | bc)
```

That should fix it.  Also, indent and add comments.

Comment: The `-e` option is unnecessary (I *hope* there aren't any escaped characters in what should be numbers).

Comment: @chepner the `-e` is needed for the \n.

Comment: Why use the non-standard `-e` option to suppress the implicit newline only to add it back explicitly?

Comment: @chepner you aren't reading-- I used the `-n` to supress the newline to show that it generates the same error the OP is getting-- that's a demonstration, not a solution.  Therefore, using `-e` to add one in is trying to make up for the one that is obviously missing.

Comment: There is no missing newline; `echo` produces one. Failing to write a newline to `bc` is *a* problem, but it's not one the OP is suffering from.

Comment: @chepner then provide an answer.  A missing newline produces the error the OP gave. If you think it's something else, then answer the question.

Comment: To avoid potential issues like this and because I think it looks nicer, I tend to just use here strings: `bc <<< "scale=4; $contador+$paraula"`